# 2 random numbers 0-100

Tags: math, random

So say I generate 2 random numbers 0-100 I need a way to some how with math idk how because I am bad with math. But some way to make a new random number with that random number that is also 0-100 and the 2 random numbers arent decimals and the output cannot be a decimal either.

I thought of subtracting but there is no way to know which one is bigger in the code i need this for. I dont' know if i can divide because wont it be a decimal?

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to do.  Please improve your grammar, and ideally provide examples of good and bad outputs.  As it stands now your question isn't going to last long.

Comment: "I need a way to some how with math" you need a way to do _what_ with math?  "the 2 random numbers arent decimals" You mean they're both integers? "nd the output cannot be a decimal either." The output of _what_?

Comment: I think he's trying to come up with a kind of hash function:

"Say I generate 2 random numbers between 1 and 100. Which mathematical operators can I use in a function to take these two random numbers and generate a new 'random' number which is also between 1 and 100?"  I'm not sure what the point of such a function would be.

Comment: which programing language are you using? Why don't you first try to generate 2 random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Assume rn1 and rn2 are 2 random number that you managed to generated, then it is not necessary to know which one bigger to generate another number.

```
diff = rn1 - rn2;
diffSquared = diff * diff;
n3 = SquareRoot(diffSquared); // positive difference
```

I let you decide usefulness of new number `n3`.

Comment: Why would you risk overflow and loss of precision when you could just do `ABS(rn1-rn2)` in virtually any language?